# Debian 7: "Failure of key exchange and association"

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, installation, debian, livecd

I'm installing Debian using the Live CD with GNOME and the non-free packages. The internet works just fine when using the live CD, but when you try to open the installer and select a network, it gives me the error of "Failure of key exchange and association". I've put everything in right, and tried multiple times. However, it never works. Am I just going to have to use ethernet to install? Thanks, people.

Comment: I have the same problem with latest Live Debian image.